# How to get the date for the occurrence of a certain value on the day

Tags: reporting-services

Good morning
I have one table in which the data is grouped daily, how to get the date for the occurrence of a specific current value in the day.
The values in the table are time and current.
The LOOKUP function does not work.

I do not have much experience with SSRS, Unfortunately, I did not find a solution on the internet.
The LOOKUP and IFF functions did not bring the expected results

Comment: Please show some sample data and what you expect the result to be, at the moment it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hpF0.png)
The query in ssrs is as follows:

```
SELECT 
YEAR (Prad.DateTime) as `Rok`,
Month (Prad.DateTime) as `Miesiac`,
Day (Prad.DateTime) as `Dzienn`,
Prad.DateTime as CzasPrad, Prad.TagName As Pompa, Prad.AVG_Prad, Prad.SUM_Prad,
Moc.DateTime as CzasMoc, Moc.Tagname as TagMoc, Moc.AVG_Moc, Moc.SUM_Moc,
Nap.DateTime as CzasNap, Nap.Tagname as TagNap, Nap.AVG_Napiecie, Nap.SUM_Napiecie, 
Czas.DateTime as CzasCzas, Czas.Tagname as TagCzas, Czas.AVG_Czas, Czas.SUM_Czas
FROM [xyDane].[dbo].[TARNOWEK_Pompy_Prad_Godzina] AS Prad
LEFT OUTER JOIN [xyDane].[dbo].[TARNOWEK_Pompy_Moc_Godzina] AS Moc ON Prad.TagName = Moc.TagName
LEFT OUTER JOIN [xyDane].[dbo].[Tarnowek_Pompy_Napiecie_Godzina] AS Nap ON Prad.TagName = Nap.TagName
LEFT OUTER JOIN [xyDane].[dbo].[TARNOWEK_Pompy_Czas_Godzina] AS Czas ON Prad.TagName = Czas.TagName
Where (Prad.DateTime = Moc.DateTime
and Prad.DateTime = Nap.DateTime
and Prad.DateTime = Czas.DateTime)and Prad.DateTime between @StartDate and @EndDate
ORDER BY Prad.DateTime, Prad.TagName
```

What function to use to insert start time and end time - A, B

[Current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXEFe.png)